# Inflection at the end of a statement?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was just wondering, is there a verb for the use of uptalk (using an inflection at the end of a statement)? So, something like this:

> I've been on several walks recentLY. (inflection at the end of a statement, as if it were a question)
>   (Some would add a question mark after such a statement, to signal the stress, but this is non-standard and confusing except when the sentence is a declarative question.)

Is there a word to express the using of such a style? (i.e. a word that can fill this blank responding to the previous sentence:)

> Stop ______!

I've already got "*sounding unsure of yourself*" or "*inflecting your sentences*", but it doesn't sound brief (or good enough). When I searched online I couldn't find anything, I just found blogposts that were just trying to convey the message "stop being indecisive".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But I'm asking this for just at the end of a statement. If I was asking for inflections in general, it would be "uptalk", yes. I don't really know how to edit the question, since it seems different from the possible duplicate already.

Comment: From the duplicate: 'It's called the rising terminal.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So, "stop rising your terminal"?

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp, probably "stop _raising_ your terminal," since "rise" is an intransitive verb (it doesn't take an object). An aside, although this is technically correct, I doubt many people would understand what you mean (since you had to look up this terminology yourself).

Comment: @vanderpn This is why I'm requesting a word...

Comment: "sounding uncertain", "intoning like a question", "cringing and just say what you mean", "your insufferable whimpering"

Comment: @TheNate I like "your insufferable whimpering", but it doesn't fit as well into this context...

Comment: Okay, yeah, that one was a *Dark Crystal* reference...

Comment: I chose the question: "I was just wondering, is there a word for _an inflection at the end of a statement?_ So, something like this:

This seems like a good place? (inflection at the end of a statement)."   If you ask two, don't be surprised if the 'other one' is answered.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Changed it a bit so that it's less ambiguous. Is it better now?

Comment: One way to deal with this annoying tick (when other people do it), is to say, *Are you asking a question?* every time they do this. After a while, they won't speak to you at all.

Answer (score -1):

"Stop uptalking!"

uptalk

/ˈʌptɔːk

noun

a manner of speaking in which declarative sentences are uttered with rising intonation at the end, as if they were questions.