# Why do English speakers sometimes raise the pitch of their voices when not asking a question?

Tags: pronunciation

When recording myself, I found that I sometimes raised the pitch of my voice when not asking a question, and not when asking a question. Why is this?

Comment: It seems to be a localised habit, to end a sentence with a raised intonation even when not asking a question. I have noticed Australians often do it and certain London accents incorporate it. Up-voted +1, as I think this is a genuine question about the English language and deserves to be taken seriously, myself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intention of rising pitches](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30855/intention-of-rising-pitches) Or [inflection at the end of a statement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/352349/inflection-at-the-end-of-a-statement/352391#352391)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a practice, called 'uptalking', or 'upspeaking', alleged to have originated independently in the western USA ('Valley Speak' has been implicated), and also in Australasia (New Zealand has been suggested).

> The high rising terminal (HRT), also known as upspeak, uptalk, rising
> inflection, upward inflection, or high rising intonation (HRI), is a
> feature of some variants of English where declarative sentence clauses
> end with a rising-pitch intonation, until the end of the sentence
> where a falling-pitch is applied.

[High Rising Terminal (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_rising_terminal)

> Final rising pitch – popularly known as “uptalk” – is an intonation
> pattern that involves rising pitch at the end of a sentence. It has
> been documented throughout the English-speaking world: in the US,
> Australia, and New Zealand; it has also been documented among ELT
> students.

[Uptalk - myth and fact (Cambridge ELT)](https://www.cambridge.org/elt/blog/2017/01/27/uptalk-english-myth-fact/)

Many native speakers (especially older ones) find uptalking annoying or irritating, although it is not as new as many suppose.

Answer (score -6):

English vocabulary, pronunciation, inconsistency, and elocution provide rich opportunities for expression. It’s a blessing, that’s all.

**Edit**

As was requested in a comment, your variations are part and parcel of your desired expression.

Comment: Can you explain how it addresses the question? It's more of a comment than am answer

Comment: Aren’t ‘am answers’ accepted any more? Oh my, this raises my ’pinion of this stack!